# Options to configure Apache to take into account other folders despite /var/www

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, and I know that if I place a php file (index.php) under /`var/www`, and I visit `localhost:80/index.php`, it will work fine.

However, say that I have multiple projects in order folders in directories such as:

```
/home/myuser/Projects/Joomla
```

and

```
/home/myuser/Work/testphp
```

What are my alternatives in order to make Apache be able to read those folders? I know I have these possibilities:

- Create symlinks (but I haven't been able to find out which permissions/groups should I set and why?)
- Add VirtualHosts (I haven't found a resource that will explain how to use VirtualHosts for this situation).

Could anyone tell me what are my possibilities and which one is the best and why?

Comment: What URLs do you want the files in those other directories to be accessible at? There are a few different methods to use, depending on the answer to that question. Or is your problem that Apache is not even able to access the files and you want to know how to set permissions to allow it to do so?

Comment: Hi David Z. It's a conceptual question, I want to know how to tell Apache to be able to access all the files from those folders, they are basically a Joomla project.

Comment: What do you mean by "I haven't found a resource that will explain how to use VirtualHosts"? You mean, that you cannot make calls with different "Host:" headers or you couldn't find an example for different VirtualHosts with different DocumentRoots?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

#### 1. Edit the default configuration file:

```
vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
```

and add this line:

```
DocumentRoot /home/myuser
```

#### 2. Create a new site configuration file:

```
touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourSite.conf
vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourSite.conf

<VirtualHost *:80> 

ServerName Joomla
DocumentRoot /home/myuser/Projects/Joomla
    <Directory /home/myuser/Projects/Joomla>
            AllowOverride all
            Options all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

#### 3. Reload your server:

```
service apache2 reload
```

You may can access now putting Joomla on the URL. If doesn't work, you should create the symlink:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourSite.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourSite.conf
```